# Laravel inserting data, different table expected

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I am new to Lavarel, I come from Zend.
I'm trying to convert the bootcamp example to one of my own and I'm not clear about the database access.
When saving, I get the following error message:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'ansprechpartner' doesn't
> have a default value (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into `t_logen`
> (`loge`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (sdsadasd, 1,
> 2024-01-07 11:51:53, 2024-01-07 11:51:53))
> Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException PHP 8.1.24
> 10.31.0 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'ansprechpartner' doesn't have a default value
>
> insert into   `t_logen` (`loge`, `user_id`, `updated_at`,
> `created_at`) values   (sdsadasd, 1, 2024 -01 -07 11: 51: 53, 2024 -01
> -07 11: 51: 53)

Obviously a different table structure is assumed.

Here is my migration, a table t_logen is created, that works.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('t_logen', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
            $table->string('loge');
            $table->string('ansprechpartner');
            $table->string('telefon');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->binary('logo');
            $table->string('orient');
            $table->string('logenhaus');
            $table->integer('logentyp');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('t_logen');
    }
};
```

Then I added a field via another migration, that also works.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::table('t_logen', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::table('t_logen', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('user_id');
        });
    }
};
```

Here my view `index.blade.php`

```
<x-app-layout>
    <div class="max-w-2xl mx-auto p-4 sm:p-6 lg:p-8">
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('arbeitskalender.store') }}">
            @csrf
            
             <textarea
                name="loge"
                placeholder="{{ __('Logenname?') }}"
                class="block w-full border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-md shadow-sm"
            >{{ old('loge') }}</textarea>
            <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('loge')" class="mt-2" />
     

            <textarea
                name="ansprechpartner"
                placeholder="{{ __('Ansprechpartner') }}"
                class="block w-full border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-md shadow-sm"
            >{{ old('ansprechpartner') }}</textarea>
            <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('ansprechpartner')" class="mt-2" />
            
            <textarea
                name="telefon"
                placeholder="{{ __('Telefon') }}"
                class="block w-full border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-md shadow-sm"
            >{{ old('telefon') }}</textarea>
            <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('telefon')" class="mt-2" />
           
            <textarea
                name="email"
                placeholder="{{ __('Email') }}"
                class="block w-full border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-md shadow-sm"
            >{{ old('email') }}</textarea>
            <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('email')" class="mt-2" />
            
            <textarea
                name="orient"
                placeholder="{{ __('Orient') }}"
                class="block w-full border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-md shadow-sm"
            >{{ old('orient') }}</textarea>
            <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('orient')" class="mt-2" />
            
            <textarea
                name="logenhaus"
                placeholder="{{ __('Logenhaus') }}"
                class="block w-full border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-md shadow-sm"
            >{{ old('logenhaus') }}</textarea>
            <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('logenhaus')" class="mt-2" />
            
            <textarea
                name="logentyp"
                placeholder="{{ __('Logentyp') }}"
                class="block w-full border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-md shadow-sm"
            >{{ old('message') }}</textarea>
            <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('logentyp')" class="mt-2" />
                            
            <div class="mt-4 space-x-2">
                <x-primary-button>{{ __('Save') }}</x-primary-button>
                <a href="{{ route('arbeitskalender.index') }}">{{ __('Cancel') }}</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</x-app-layout>
```

Additional my "`LogenController.php`" action

```
 public function store(Request $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        //
        $validated = $request->validate([                   //validierung
            'loge' => 'required|string|max:255',
             'ansprechpartner' => 'required|string|max:255',
             'telefon' => 'required|string|max:255',
             'email' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'orient' => 'required|string|max:255',
        ]);
        $request->user()->logen()->create($validated);      //speichern in Datenbank user()->
       
//         $input = Request::all();
//         Logen::create[$input];
        return redirect(route('arbeitskalender.index'));
    }
```

The Model `Logen.php`

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;

class Logen extends Model
{
    protected $table = 't_logen';
    use HasFactory;
    
    protected $fillable = [         //Massenabfrage ermöglichen
        'loge',
        'ansprechpartner',
    ];
    
//     protected $dispatchesEvents = [
//         'created' => LogeCreated::class,
//     ];
    
    public function user(): BelongsTo           //chirps eines bestimmten Users
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
   
}
```

And the User.php Class

```
namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'password' => 'hashed',
    ];
    
    public function logen(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Logen::class);
    }
}
```

If I remove the `protected $table = 't_logen'` in the model;
in the model, the following message appears:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
> 'chirper.logens' doesn't exist`

Obviously a table "logens" is expected, what is the connection? Where can I find this entry?
I would be very grateful if someone could briefly explain the exact connections to me.

Comment: Have you also tried assigning a value to the "ansprechpartner" field when entering data

Comment: Is `ansprechpartner` declared `NOT NULL` in the database?

Comment: Yes I assigned a value. but look at the error message, the insert doesn't expect this column, that's what I don't understand

Comment: update migrate $table->string('ansprechpartner')->nullable(); try if it solves the problem than you should check with some validation this field must be filled when saving the record in the datatabase.